# Is there a simpler way of associating a key to a value in a mapped obect?

Tags: typescript

I have an object where the value directly relates to the key, meaning that this would be valid:

```
const x = {
  test(action: { type: 'test', payload: unknown }){ /*...*/ }
}
```

but this would not be valid:

```
const x = {
  test(action: { type: 'notTest', payload: unknown }){ /*...*/ }
}
```

I'm helping myself to achieve this be creating an implicit generic type that is nevery specified or used directly, but which flows through a second map for validation.

So my solution looks like this:

```
type Action<T> = {type: T};

interface ActionListenerMiddlewareListener<A extends Action<any>> {
  (action: A): void
}

export type CaseListeners = Record<
  string,
  ActionListenerMiddlewareListener<any>
>

export type CaseListenersCheck<Listeners extends CaseListeners> = {
  [T in keyof Listeners]: Listeners[T] extends ActionListenerMiddlewareListener<
    infer A
  >
    ? A extends { type: T }
      ? Listeners[T]
      : /* 
      Type is not matching the object key. 
      Return ActionListenerMiddlewareListener<Action<T>> to hint in the resulting error message that this is wrong.
      */ ActionListenerMiddlewareListener<
          Action<T>
        >
    : never
}

export type ValidCaseListeners<Listeners extends CaseListeners> = Listeners &
  CaseListenersCheck<Listeners>

export function createActionListenerMiddleware<Listeners extends CaseListeners>(
  cases: ValidCaseListeners<Listeners>
): any {
    // ...

}
```

But of course, I'd rather like to have one type that checks for this validity instead of this implicit-generic-that-is-restricted-on-the-spot construct I have right now.

**Is there a simpler way to write this?**

Comment: Please consider editing the code to constitute a self-contained [mcve] that can be dropped into an IDE to demonstrate the issue you're seeing.  Right now I don't understand why `"test"` is good and `"notTest"` is bad, nor does your solution code compile as it refers to undeclared types.  So I'm too confused to give any advice here.

Comment: Sorry, I'll rework it a bit.

As it does not seem to be clear.
"notTest" is not good, because I want a relation between the key `"test"` and the value `function(arg: {type: "test"}): void`.

That is true in the first example "test" == "test", but not in the second "test" != "notTest". I want users from using values that do not *literally* match the key in their values.

Comment: Should work on it's own now. It's still a bit contrived, but in my case I want the literal type value of the function parameter to match the key name, so I don't think there's a shorter way to write it.

Comment: The constraint needs to be generic, there's no escaping that. The specific generic could possibly be simplified or at least made more terse, such as [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAFgWwTAvDAPAFRgUwB5Q5gAmEMA3gLABQMMA2gNIwCWYMA1jgJ4gBmMTAF0AXDAAUAQ2BQW4MQHkELKOgAKkgE6SEOQpohYmQgHz0ADEIA0MAERRuABxy2TMAGQUYD52OYBfAEpUNwA3EBZiGn8TcSgxTGCUNygAbhoaUEhYPFR4JHEqWm8caCkZOTAxcm8nHDEAckJoBptHSW4AGxBJYjEAVzAOMBAAd3YgrwB6ACoAOgWZqZh-K2jAjOos6BhuPMQEQpo6Zqhy2XkvH3qYBpGoTFKoVph2rp6+mEHhsYngmtmCzmSxWa2oQU2QA). Let me know if you want that fleshed out to an answer.

Comment: Never thought of referencing something in it's own `extends`. That's genius, thank you!